# Spring Data Neo4j 4 doesn't recognize domain objects housed in a jar file

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I wasted a day on this, but it appears that Spring Data Neo4j 4 will not load domain objects from a jar file. I had a simple war container and within it I had a jar file containing all my domain objects. I kept getting class cast exceptions and struggled to figure out why. I finally noticed that none of my domain objects were being recognized. Only after I removed the classes from the jar and added them directly to the war did it work. I assume this is a bug with the framework. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: Do you have an example somewhere? A jar of domain objects works fine when included in a spring boot app. What version of neo4j-ogm is included in your project?

Comment: neo4j-ogm-1.1.2. Running in Tomcat 8. Do you think the version is the issue? I could try using 1.1.4 and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Would be great if you could try 1.1.4

Comment: That didn't work. 1.1.4 has the same issue.

Comment: I'm begining to beleive it's a Windows issue. In ClassPathScanner on line 139 there is a classPathElement with the path (C:\\Program%20Files\\Apache\\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\\webapps\\rad-neo4j-service\\WEB-INF\\lib\\core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) However, classPathElement.exists() returns false, which I suspect has something to do with the path.

Comment: Just confirmed that it was the location of my webapp causing the issue. After moving it outside of "Program Files" it worked fine.